# Adobe AIR Native extension: have multiple context in same Native Extension

Tags: ios, air, adobe, air-native-extension, ane

I am developing a native extension for iOS and Android for Adobe AIR.
I want to generate a single file .ane, but I wish I could call my native extension with multiple contexts.

Android is easy, just asked to test the context parameter in the function of public FREContext CreateContext (String pExtensionName) ', and return an instance in context as a parameter.

But how can I do that iOS?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found how to do it, you have to test the variable ctxType which contains the context name in the function 'ContextInitializer".